# Bypassing human verification with selenium library

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, data-mining

as part of a project, I entered site [Taylor & Francis online] ("https://www.tandfonline.com/loi/nvpp20") using selenium library in python
to bypass human verification .

I tried this code:
`

```
import pandas as pd


import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
import undetected_chromedriver as uc
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from fake_useragent import UserAgent

import time
import os

url = "https://www.tandfonline.com/loi/nvpp20"
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("window-size=1400,500")
ua = UserAgent()
user_agent = ua.random
options.add_argument(f'--user-agent={user_agent}')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.get(url)
WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//*[@id="1d69ec8f-0b13-42ca-bc6d-f5a385caf8c4"]/div/div/div/a[1]'))).click()
time.sleep(10)
login = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="frmLogin"]/div[2]/ul/li/a').click()
```

`

I got this message in the browser : [message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v2oyn.png)
and this error :
`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\97254\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\Final_assignment.py", line 32, in <module>
    login = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="frmLogin"]/div[2]/ul/li/a').click()
  File "C:\Users\97254\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 740, in find_element
    return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {"using": by, "value": value})["value"]
  File "C:\Users\97254\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 346, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\97254\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 245, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="frmLogin"]/div[2]/ul/li/a"}
  (Session info: chrome=114.0.5735.199); For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/troubleshooting/errors#no-such-element-exception
Stacktrace:
Backtrace:
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00FBA813+48355]
    (No symbol) [0x00F4C4B1]
    (No symbol) [0x00E55358]
    (No symbol) [0x00E809A5]
    (No symbol) [0x00E80B3B]
    (No symbol) [0x00EAE232]
    (No symbol) [0x00E9A784]
    (No symbol) [0x00EAC922]
    (No symbol) [0x00E9A536]
    (No symbol) [0x00E782DC]
    (No symbol) [0x00E793DD]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x0121AABD+2539405]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x0125A78F+2800735]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x0125456C+2775612]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x010451E0+616112]
    (No symbol) [0x00F55F8C]
    (No symbol) [0x00F52328]
    (No symbol) [0x00F5240B]
    (No symbol) [0x00F44FF7]
    BaseThreadInitThunk [0x76197D59+25]
    RtlInitializeExceptionChain [0x7766B74B+107]
    RtlClearBits [0x7766B6CF+191]`
```

but my google chrome is up to date - version 114.0.5735.199.
I want to proceed into login in order to scrape articles from every issue, without any annoying messages or captchas.